# How do i access the file datas changes that were made in Heroku?

Tags: database, web, heroku

I added my app on heroku and it makes changes to the file inside it and everytime i make a change in github all the datas are lost is there any way i can get access to the file inside heroku

Comment: That's not ideal to keep files inside your server because when you deploy it will create a new build where all the files will be cleared, For whatever reason you are suing files try to host those file somewhere else and excess them from your server or you can use a db for the same 

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has an “ephemeral” hard drive, this means that you can write files to disk, but those files will not persist after the application is restarted with the dynos. The best solution to this problem is to use cloud storage and dump all the new data on it with your worker script.